# CentOS Property-based compare-operations Rsyslog

Tags: linux, logging, filter, centos, rsyslog

I´m using CentOS and I´m looking for a solution to filter some messages from /var/log/messages by tag to user defined file.
I´m trying something like that in /etc/rsyslog.conf

*:msg, contains, "mytag" /var/log/mytag/mytag.log*

but it doesnt work.
I think I´m not far away from a solution.
I used this documentation for researching: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-basic_configuration_of_rsyslog.html

Do I have to *touch* the new logfile by myself and which File and Directory Permissions are needed.

Do you have a idea to fix my problem?

Comment: So i tried some other configurations. The solution with
:msg, contains, "mytag" /var/log/mytag/mytag.log
is working just for my tag "dnsmasq" it doesnt work, but i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by using the option 'log-facility=/path/' in dnsmasq.conf
But this don't solve to problem completely, because I want to seperate dns and dhcp in different files.

If you have a better solution, let me know :)